# WPF imaging problems

Tags: wpf, multithreading, image

Okay I have a an wpf image object, and it displays live images. So I have used a timer to refresh the image.

```
    public void LoadLiveImage()
        {

System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat pf = PixelFormats.Bgr24;
                    int stride = 4 * ((24 * cameraFrame.img_width + 31) / 32); 
                     BitmapSource bmpImage=  BitmapSource.Create(cameraFrame.img_width, cameraFrame.img_height, cameraFrame.img_width, cameraFrame.img_height, pf, null, cameraFrame.img_pixel, stride);
                    RemoteCameraImage.Source = bmpImage;
}

 void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             LoadLiveImage();           

        }
```

No issues, this is working fine.
However, I tried to move this to a thread and no image is displayed.

```
 private void showLiveImage()
        {
                while (this.isCameraViewOpen)
                {
                 if (RemoteCameraImage.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                        {
                            System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat pf = PixelFormats.Bgr24;
                            int stride = 4 * ((24 * cameraFrame.img_width + 31) / 32); 
                            BitmapSource bmpImage = BitmapSource.Create(cameraFrame.img_width, cameraFrame.img_height, cameraFrame.img_width, cameraFrame.img_height, pf, null, cameraFrame.img_pixel, stride);
                            RemoteCameraImage.Source = bmpImage;

                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
                        }
                        else
                            this.RemoteCameraImage.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new ImageUpdater(this.showLiveImage));

                    }

}
```

The showLiveImage isrunning as a thread. The image is received, there is not problem in that. I tested by saving the img_pixel array to a bmp file and file is generated. Just that the image is not displayed on. So I put a messagebox to be shown after the source is assigned, and then I m able to see the image on Image object. SO I think the problem I increased the Sleep time, but even the image is not refreshed. WHAT could be the issue?

EDIT:
After moving the code which was updating the image to another function, it works fine. And I used BeginInvoke() instead of invoke an all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime ago I had similiar problems and I found this on Stackoverflow, which sovled it for me

[Images on second thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034902/how-do-you-pass-a-bitmapimage-from-a-background-thread-to-the-ui-thread-in-wpf)

[WPF Dispatcher {"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982498/wpf-dispatcher-the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-differen)

> If you have no intention of modifying the image once you have created
>   it you can freeze it using Freezable.Freeze and then assign to
>   GeneratedImage in the dispatcher delegate (the BitmapImage becomes
>   read-only and thus threadsafe as a result of the Freeze). The other
>   option would be to load the image into a MemoryStream on the
>   background thread and then create the BitmapImage on the UI thread in
>   the dispatcher delegate with that stream and the StreamSource property
>   of BitmapImage.

Comment: The problem is not with dispatcher not being able to access the object. If I add some user action in the thread, like MessageBox, the the image gets displayed. I tried the freeze also, it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **Application.Current.Dispatcher** instead of the one you used.
I believe this will do the trick.

Cheers