# How do I display changing images in a multithreaded WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, image

I'm working on a project where we need to capture and process images in order to control a robot. Those two things are working just fine.

What I can't seem to be able to figure out is how to use WPF to display the pre- and post-processing images.

I have an app that is using this code:

```
public CamNotification(string label1, string label2, BitmapSource image1, BitmapSource image2)

private bool hwLink_SetInfos(CamNotification info)
{
    try
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            lblText1.Content = info.Label1;
            lblText2.Content = info.Label2;

            ImageBox1.Source = info.Image1;
            ImageBox2.Source = info.Image2;
            InvalidateVisual();
        }));
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        return false;
    }
}
```

It changes both the labels describing the images and the 'image.source's themselves.

It works ->[fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIeJy.png)<- when I use a WPF-button to call the code, but when I try it using a WorkerThread from a Threadpool that replaces the two 'image.source's the images are not displayed, even though the labels are.

Moreover, if I have already pressed the button and the pictures were displayed, a call from the ->[WorkerThread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T53PI.png)<- that ends up in the MainThread removes the images and leaves a blank area instead of updating them to the new content.

Using the Dispatcher I have already removed all crossthead-issues, Labels are updated but the "PresentationFramework -> System.Windows.Controls.Image" is cleard and not updated :-(

While looking through stackoverflow I found this question:

[WPF imaging problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116563/wpf-imaging-problems)

It seems to be concerned with a problem similar to mine. However, neither the answers nor the OPs comment about how he solved his problem have helped me.

I would appreciate any help you could give me.

Comment: It sounds like an issue with the image not being frozen. Did you try calling info.Image1.Freeze() and info.Image2.Freeze() before setting the source?

Comment: @Tone That was it. Thank you very much. For those interested: I put info.image1.Freeze() and info.image2.Freeze() after the try{ but before the Dispatcher. Works like a charm now ^^

Comment: Good to hear. I've added a full answer for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BitmapImageSource is a freezable object which should be be frozen if you intend to access it across threads

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509(v=vs.100).aspx)

> A Freezable provides a Changed event to notify observers of any
>   modifications to the object. Freezing a Freezable can improve its
>   performance, because it no longer needs to spend resources on change
>   notifications. A frozen Freezable can also be shared across threads,
>   while an unfrozen Freezable cannot.

...

> A freezable's Freeze method enables you to disable this self-updating
>   ability. You can use this method to make the brush become "frozen," or
>   unmodifiable.

As you're working with the images on another thread, you need to change your code to call `Freeze()` before it can be used on the UI thread. Some working code below

```
public CamNotification(string label1, string label2, BitmapSource image1, BitmapSource image2)

private bool hwLink_SetInfos(CamNotification info)
{
    try
    {
        info.Image1.Freeze();
        info.Image2.Freeze();

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            lblText1.Content = info.Label1;
            lblText2.Content = info.Label2;

            ImageBox1.Source = info.Image1;
            ImageBox2.Source = info.Image2;
            InvalidateVisual();
        }));
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        return false;
    }
}
```

A couple of related articles:

[How do you pass a BitmapImage from a background thread to the UI thread in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034902/how-do-you-pass-a-bitmapimage-from-a-background-thread-to-the-ui-thread-in-wpf)

[In what scenarios does freezing WPF objects benefit performance greatly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799911/in-what-scenarios-does-freezing-wpf-objects-benefit-performance-greatly)