# How to make the whole application responsive rather than the individual UI Controls using async and await?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, async-ctp

I am using `async` and `await` keywords to make an app responsive

I have the following code in the `View` when the property is raised in the `ViewModel`.

**VIEW: Button Click Event**

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.IsEnabled = false;

        // Property Change
        _viewModel.Words = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => File.ReadAllLines("Words.txt").ToList()); // takes time to read about 3 - 4 seconds

        switch (_viewModel.RadioButtonWordOrderSelection)
        {
            case MainWindowViewModel.RadioButtonWordOrderSelections.NormalOrder:
                break;

            case MainWindowViewModel.RadioButtonWordOrderSelections.ReverseOrder:
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                                {
                                                    var words = _viewModel.Words.ToList();
                                                    words.Reverse();
                                                    // Property Change
                                                    _viewModel.Words = words;
                                                });
                break;

            case MainWindowViewModel.RadioButtonWordOrderSelections.Shuffle:
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                                {
                                                    // Property Change
                                                    _viewModel.Words = _viewModel.Words.Shuffle().ToList();
                                                });
                break;
        }

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DownloadSomething(_viewModel.Words)); // takes time to read about 30 - 40 seconds

        button1.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

`_viewModel.Progress` gets updated in the `View`

**VIEW: Private Method Takes 30 - 40 seconds To Complete**

```
    private void DownloadSomething(IEnumerable<string> words)
    {
        // Property Change
        _viewModel.Progress = 0;

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            // Property Change
            _viewModel.Word = word;
            try
            {
                // Some code WebClient download code here
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            // Property Change
            _viewModel.Progress++;
        }
    }
```

**VIEW: Property Change Event Handled**

```
    void _viewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            switch(e.PropertyName)
            {
                case "Progress":
                    // Since its a different Thread
                    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx
                    // Sets the Value on a ProgressBar Control.
                    // This will work as its using the dispatcher

                    // The following works
                    //Dispatcher.Invoke(
                    //    DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                    //    new Action<double>(SetProgressValue), 
                    //    _viewModel.Progress);

                    // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982498/wpf-dispatcher-the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-differen
                    progress1.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                        DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                        new Action(() =>
                        {
                            progress1.Value = _viewModel.Progress;
                        })
                    );

                    // This will throw an exception 
                    // (it's on the wrong thread)
                    //progress1.Value = _viewModel.Progress;
                    break;

                case "Words":
                    // Since its a different Thread
                    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx
                    // Sets the Max Value on a ProgressBar Control.
                    // This will work as its using the dispatcher

                    // The following Works
                    //Dispatcher.Invoke(
                    //    DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    //    new Action<double>(SetProgressMaxValue),
                    //    _viewModel.Words.Count);

                    // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982498/wpf-dispatcher-the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-differen
                    progress1.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                        DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                        new Action(() =>
                        {
                            progress1.Maximum = _viewModel.Words.Count;
                        })
                    );

                    // This will throw an exception 
                    // (it's on the wrong thread)
                    //progress1.Maximum = _viewModel.Words.Count;
                    break;

                case "Word":
                    // Since its a different Thread
                    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx
                    // Sets the Contant on a Label Control.
                    // This will work as its using the dispatcher

                    // The following Works
                    //Dispatcher.Invoke(
                    //    DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    //    new Action<string>(SetLastWordValue),
                    //    _viewModel.Word);

                    // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982498/wpf-dispatcher-the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-differen
                    labelLastWord.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                        DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                        new Action(() =>
                        {
                            labelLastWord.Content = _viewModel.Word;
                        })
                    );

                    // This will throw an exception 
                    // (it's on the wrong thread)
                    //labelLastWord.Content = _viewModel.Word;
                    break;

                case "RadioButtonWordOrderSelection":
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException("[Not implemented for 'Property Name': " + e.PropertyName + "]");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

The UI updates perfectly for the progressBar1 and labelLastWord! I am facing a problem though, when  progressBar1 and labelLastWord is updating the rest of the UI is frozen.

Is there a work around to fix this?

I greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: In Wpf you should be using Commands rather than the code behind. Then you can easily async/await within the Command.

Comment: About the edited title, see [Should questions include tags in their titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Comment: @JordanKaye can you suggest me a good place to start with Commands? Thanks for your response!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you follow the guidelines in the [Task-based Async Programming document](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957). This is far better than just shunting work off to the thread pool via `StartNew`. If you *do* have CPU-bound operations, you could use `Task.Run`, but for everything else, use the existing `async`-ready endpoints.

Also, I find it useful to treat the entire VM as being in the UI context. So `PropertyChanged` is always raised in a UI context. Data binding in particular depends on this.

```
private async Task<List<string>> ReadAllLinesAsync(string file)
{
  var ret = new List<string>();
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
  {
    string str = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
    while (str != null)
    {
      ret.Add(str);
      str = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  button1.IsEnabled = false;

  _viewModel.Words = await ReadAllLinesAsync("Words.txt");

  List<string> words;
  switch (_viewModel.RadioButtonWordOrderSelection)
  {
    case MainWindowViewModel.RadioButtonWordOrderSelections.NormalOrder:
      break;

    case MainWindowViewModel.RadioButtonWordOrderSelections.ReverseOrder:
      await Task.Run(() =>
      {
        words = _viewModel.Words.ToList();
        words.Reverse();
      });
      _viewModel.Words = words;
      break;

    case MainWindowViewModel.RadioButtonWordOrderSelections.Shuffle:
      await Task.Run(() =>
      {
        words = _viewModel.Words.Shuffle().ToList();
      });
      _viewModel.Words = words;
      break;
  }

  await DownloadSomething(_viewModel.Words);

  button1.IsEnabled = true;
}

private async Task DownloadSomething(IEnumerable<string> words)
{
  _viewModel.Progress = 0;

  foreach (var word in words)
  {
    _viewModel.Word = word;
    try
    {
      await ...; // async WebClient/HttpClient code here
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      //Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    _viewModel.Progress++;
  }
}

void _viewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    switch(e.PropertyName)
    {
      case "Progress":
        progress1.Value = _viewModel.Progress;
        break;

      case "Words":
        progress1.Maximum = _viewModel.Words.Count;
        break;

      case "Word":
        labelLastWord.Content = _viewModel.Word;
        break;

      case "RadioButtonWordOrderSelection":
        break;

      default:
        throw new NotImplementedException("[Not implemented for 'Property Name': " + e.PropertyName + "]");
    }
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
  }
}
```

As a closing note, I recommend you purchase and read thoroughly [Josh Smith's MVVM book](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/advanced-mvvm/). You're using terms like "View" and "ViewModel", but the way you're using these components, you're *completely* avoiding all the advantages of the MVVM pattern.